# Programatically clear product group prices - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: product, group-price

I am trying to programatically clear a product's group prices within a custom module. Thisi s my code:

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); // for debug only
try
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $product->setGroupPrice(null);
    $product->save();
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo "Error: ". $ex->getMessage();
}
```

When this code executes, I get the following exception:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 1180

In the `system.log` file, I see allot of these entries:

> 2016-03-17T18:01:06+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied
>   for foreach()  in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 1180 2016-03-17T18:01:06+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error:
>   Argument 3 passed to
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract::_canUpdateAttribute() must be of
>   the type array, null given, called in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 1225 and defined  in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php
>   on line 543 2016-03-17T18:01:06+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error:
>   Argument 3 passed to
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_canUpdateAttribute() must be of the
>   type array, null given, called in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php
>   on line 545 and defined  in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 1254 2016-03-17T18:01:06+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 1256

Any idea what might be causing this? The same code on my dev magento setup works, but in production magento, this error started to appear, so I am a little confused.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've probably have solved this problem already, but for other people looking for resolution - you need to set store scope first.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Do you have any idea why you need to set the store ID manually? Also, it's a bit weird that the error message isn't quite helpful...

Comment: Why need to set admin store id when product save from frontend